# Scheme - Lambda as a Bad Function Object

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, r5rs

I'm working on a metacircular evaluator in Scheme for homework, and I need to allow the user to install special forms by adding them to a table. The idea is that, when the user enters something like `(square 5)`, the evaluator will look up forms named `square`. If it's found, it will return a `lambda` statement, something like `(lambda (x) (* x x))`.

I'm having a problem when the code returns the `lambda` statement. I get the following error message:

```
Error: Bad function object:(lambda (x) (* x x))
```

The really strange part is that I can pass parameters into functions retrieved from my table, it's just that I have to previously define the procedure body as a lambda statement, not as a list that starts with `lambda`

For reference, here's the code that doesn't work. `exp` will be something like `(install-special-form 'square (lambda (x) (* x x)))`, so in this case, `name` evaluates to `square` and `func` evaluates to `(lambda (x) (* x x))`:

```
(define (install-eval exp)
  (define name (cadadr exp))
  (define func (caddr exp))
    (if (special-form-lookup (list name func))
        #f
       (begin
         (append! special-forms-table (list name func))
         name)))
```

And here's some code that does work:

```
(define (install exp-list)
  (append! special-forms-table exp-list))
(install (list 'square (lambda (x) (* x x))))
```

I'm guessing my problem is that, when using the code that doesn't work, `lambda` is evaluated as a quote, rather than an actual `lambda`? How can I get my user input to store an actual `lambda` statement that can be retrieved and used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably storing the lambda as a list of symbols, not as an actual procedure. That's why this won't work:

```
(define f '(lambda (x) (* x x)))
(f 10)
=> Error: Bad function object: (lambda (x) (* x x))
```

Try evaluating it first:

```
((eval f) 10)
=> 100
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: And in a interpreter where you use `eval` how would free variables work?

Answer (score 1):

When you return the **list** `(lambda (x) (* x x))` you cannot apply it with the host since it would be like doing `('(lambda (x) (* x x)) 5)`. Try it. you'll get the same error.

When Scheme evaluates the special form `(lambda (x) (* x x))` it returns a closure object with the environment to when it was created. When you call it it will run the body with that environment with the added bingind to `x`. This needs to be simulated in your interpreter so usually `(lamba (args ...) body)` usually is evaluated to `(closure-tag (args ...) environment body)`. Your apply needs these to be able to call `eval` on the body with that correct environment. Oscars suggestion to use `eval` won't work in the long run since you won't be able to make closures in the interpreter with `eval` and I would consider it cheating if you did get away with it.